# Checking for underflow/overflow in C++?

Tags: c++, overflow, integer-overflow, underflow

Is there a general way to check for an overflow or an underflow of a given data type (uint32, int etc.)?

I am doing something like this:

```
uint32 a,b,c;
... //initialize a,b,c
if(b < c) {
   a -= (c - b)
}
```

When I print a after some iterations, it displays a large number like: 4294963846.

Comment: [How to detect integer overflow in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/199333/995714)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To check for over/underflow in arithmetic check the result compared to the original values.

```
uint32 a,b;
//assign values
uint32 result = a + b;
if (result < a) {
    //Overflow
}
```

For your specific the check would be:

```
if (a > (c-b)) {
    //Underflow
}
```

Comment: is this the fact that in case of overflow the answer will always be a signed ( negative integer) ?

Comment: Overflow of unsigned integers will never be signed, rather it will be  a smaller unsigned integer than either of the original values.

Comment: Take care, signed overflow is undefined behavior in C.

Answer (score 4):

I guess if I wanted to do that I would make a class that simulates the data type, and do it manually (which would be slow I would imagine)

```
class MyInt
{
     int val;
     MyInt(const int&nval){ val = nval;} // cast from int
     operator int(){return val;} // cast to int

    // then just overload ALL the operators... putting your check in
};

//typedef int sint32;
typedef MyInt sint32;
```

it can be more tricky than that, you might have to wind up using a define instead of a typedef...

I did a similar thing with pointers to check where memory was being written out side of bounds. very slow but did find where memory was being corrupted

Comment: There's a version of this [called SafeInt](http://safeint.codeplex.com/) that I learned about tonight.  It's probably not a bad idea to use something like that most of the time, just not in performance critical code.

Answer (score 3):

Cert has a good reference for both [signed integer overflow](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow) which is undefined behavior and [unsigned wrapping](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT30-C.+Ensure+that+unsigned+integer+operations+do+not+wrap) which is not and they cover all the operators.

The document provides the following checking code for unsigned wrapping in subtraction using preconditions is as follows:

```
void func(unsigned int ui_a, unsigned int ui_b) {
  unsigned int udiff;
  if (ui_a < ui_b){
    /* Handle error */
  } else {
    udiff = ui_a - ui_b;
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

and with post-conditions:

```
void func(unsigned int ui_a, unsigned int ui_b) {
  unsigned int udiff = ui_a - ui_b;
  if (udiff > ui_a) {
    /* Handle error */
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

If you are [gcc 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) you can use `__builtin_sub_overflow`:

```
__builtin_sub_overflow( ui_a, ui_b, &udiff )
```

Answer (score 0):

Boost has a neat library called Safe Numerics. Depending on how you instantiate the safe template, the library will throw an exception when overflow or underflow has occurred. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/safe_numerics/doc/html/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put here another possible approach in case a *bigger* (x2 size) integer type is available. In that case it is possible to prevent the overflow from happening at the expense of a little more computation.

```
// https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fh9G6Eeah
#include <exception>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

using integer_t = uint32_t; // The desired type
using bigger_t = uint64_t; // Bigger type

constexpr integer_t add(const integer_t a, const integer_t b)
   {
    static_assert(sizeof(bigger_t)>=2*sizeof(integer_t));
    constexpr bigger_t SUP = std::numeric_limits<integer_t>::max();
    constexpr bigger_t INF = std::numeric_limits<integer_t>::min();
    // Using larger type for operation
    bigger_t res = static_cast<bigger_t>(a) + static_cast<bigger_t>(b);
    // Check overflows
    if(res>SUP) throw std::overflow_error("res too big");
    else if(res<INF) throw std::overflow_error("res too small");
    // Back to the original type
    return static_cast<integer_t>(res); // No danger of narrowing here
   }


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    std::cout << add(100,1) << '\n';
    std::cout << add(std::numeric_limits<integer_t>::max(),1) << '\n';
}
```